# IQKeyboardManager unexpected behavior

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift4

i have a simple chat view that contain table view, text field and a send button 
i'm using IQKeyboardManager  to handle keyboard appearance but the unexpected behavior is that when i click on send button the keyboard disappear that behavior don't happen on chat apps like whatsApp the keyboard remain appear' 
how to handle this behavior to be like whatsApp 
Update : here is the send button code

```
 @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    //TODO: Send the message to Firebase and save it in our database

    if (messageTextfield.text?.isEmpty)!{
        showAlert(alertTitle: "", alertMessage: "can't send empty Message", actionTiltle: "Ok")
    }
    else{
        messageTextfield.isEnabled=false
        sendButton.isEnabled=false
        let messageDB=Database.database().reference().child("Messages")
        let dictionary:[String:String]=["Sender":(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!,"MessageBody":messageTextfield.text!]
        messageDB.childByAutoId().setValue(dictionary)
        messageTextfield.text=""
        messageTextfield.isEnabled=true
        sendButton.isEnabled=true

    }

}
```

Comment: may be in code you resign the textfield that's why it resign.

Comment: @chiragshah updated with the code

Comment: remove isEnable code and check the output

Comment: it work well after deleating isEnable but i need to disable textMessage and the button until the message is sent , how can i do that

Comment: then used isUserInterationEnable = false may this works

Comment: thanks for your help , i was searching to know where is the problem and this take me a lot of time

Comment: so now you got the answer where the problem is. happy coading

Comment: that's great but i notice one little thing when i use isUserInteractionEnable instead of isEnable , the text field and the button disappear and reappear in a flash manner what may cause this?
and if you tell me why isUserInterationEnable  make the keyboard behavior well and not went well in  isEnable  it will be great for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176123/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-bent-el-eslam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with isEnable property used isUserInteration property instead of that

```
@IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    //TODO: Send the message to Firebase and save it in our database

    if (messageTextfield.text?.isEmpty)!{
        showAlert(alertTitle: "", alertMessage: "can't send empty Message", actionTiltle: "Ok")
    }
    else{
        messageTextfield.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
        let messageDB=Database.database().reference().child("Messages")
        let dictionary:[String:String]=["Sender":(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!,"MessageBody":messageTextfield.text!]
        messageDB.childByAutoId().setValue(dictionary)
        messageTextfield.text=""
        messageTextfield.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled=true

    }

}
```